# exe file made in python doesn't run

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have a made a GUI in python and am trying to make an executable app for it. 
I have used both `pyinstaller` and `py2exe` for making the `.exe` file.

I have used:

```
c:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\pyinstaller-develop\pyinstaller.py --onedir --name=Spectroscopylib SVS-virtual-lib-2.py
```

for pyinstaller and:

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe
setup(console=['SVS-virtual-lib.py'])

python setup.py py2exe
```

for py2exe.

I managed to create the `dist` folder containing the `exe` file with both approaches, but when I try to run the file, it doesn't execute.

The command window appears for a short time and then disappears.

The error in `pyinstaller` is:

```
No module famed filedialog
```

And error in `py2exe` is:

```
couldn't find matplotlib data file
```

Dose anyone know what I can do?

I am using python 2.7 and `pycharm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install matplotlib (pip install matplotlib) and then put it in the data_files.

```
import matplotlib
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
console = [{'script': r'your_path'}]
)
```

Comment: Thank you... now i am running the file it gives me the following error:                   File "C:\Users\zarinabn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 305, in _run
    dlls = self.find_dlls(extensions)
  File "C:\Users\zarinabn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 389, in find_dlls
    self.dll_excludes)
  File "C:\Users\zarinabn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1021, in find_dependend_dlls
    import py2exe_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

For the py2exe case it sounds like you missed adding matplotlib files that are needed but cannot be auto-detected by py2exe.
There's a dedicated small document for using matplotlib in py2exe applications:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

The important part is adding datafiles to the py2exe package:

> ```
> import matplotlib
> ...
> setup(
>     ...
>     data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
> )
> ```